# Uploading image to my server with CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have a problem when uploading an image to my server with CKEditor, I have set the following on `ckeditor/config.js`:

`config.imageUploadUrl = 'http://www.example.com/upload.php';`

Everything is fine, I receive the picture on my php code and I return this:

`json_encode([
    "uploaded" => 1,
    "fileName" => "1942981318392_4135970866535506445_n.jpg",
    "url" => $url])`

And CKEditor shows me a message that the image was successfully uploaded, but so far I have a problem is that the image link is not updated in src image on textarea . How do I solve this problem?
Thank you very much

Comment: Have you checked the contents of `$url`?

Comment: Yes I return the image link correctly, usually if i send a wrong link, Ckeditor will display an error message to me

Comment: So, you are using dropped or pasted image, CKEditor informs you with this green infobox that the image was successfully uploaded, but you don't see the image at all in WYSIWYG and Source editing areas? Can you please post just for clarification the image url for your example?